# Interactive batch file problems

Tags: batch-file, interactive

I've just begun trying to learn to write batch files, and I think I've got some or most of the basics, but I just can't seem to figure this out.

Is it possible to have a batch file ask for the user to enter a sub folder name and then change the current directory to that sub-folder?

For example, say my current directory is C:\Folder. This folder has the sub-folders Sub 1, Sub 2, and Sub 3. If the user needs to browse to one of these folders, but which one may vary each time the file is run, is it possible to have the user input the sub-folder name and then have the batch file change the current directory to that folder?

Maybe something like:

```
CD C:\Folder

SET /p desiredFolder = Enter the name of the sub-folder you would like to go to: 
Sub 1, Sub 2, or Sub 3

---User enters Sub 1 and hits enter---

CD C:\Folder\%desiredFolder%
```

Thank you in advance for any help provided!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost done, just a couple details missing:

1- When use any form of SET command do NOT include spaces before the equal sign; otherwise the variable name *include* the space:

```
SET VAR = VALUE
ECHO %VAR%               show nothing
ECHO %VAR %              show " VALUE"
```

2- If the folder name may contain spaces, you must enclose *the whole folder name* in quotes:

```
CD C:\Folder

SET /p desiredFolder=Enter the name of the sub-folder you would like to go to: 
Sub 1, Sub 2, or Sub 3

---User enters Sub 1 and hits enter---

CD "C:\Folder\%desiredFolder%"
```

Comment: Actually, `CD` doesn't require enclosing the path in double quotes, but getting into the habit of doing so wouldn't harm, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You might even try:

```
@echo off
:start
set desiredFolder=
dir /AD /W /B
echo.---------------------------------------------------------
set /p desiredFolder=Enter the name of the folder you would like to go to: 
echo %CD%\%desiredFolder%
IF NOT EXIST %CD%\%desiredFolder% echo..\%desiredFolder% does not exist, try again. 
IF NOT EXIST %CD%\%desiredFolder% echo.--------------------------------------------------------- & goto start
```

Then Use one of the following after the line above depending on what you want to do

```
start cmd.exe /K chdir %CD%\%desiredFolder%
REM if you want to start your command window in a new directory

cmd.exe /K chdir %CD%\%desiredFolder%
REM if you want to change directories in your current command window

start %CD%\%desiredFolder%
REM if you want to open the folder in windows explorer
```